# Why are cotton shop towels usually red?

Tags: mechanics-trade

Cotton shop towels are often dyed red, like the one this dude is using to wipe down his impact driver (gotta keep those tools clean).

Why are shop towels often red? I'm thinking it's to make sure grizzly mechanics and maintenance folk are destined to have pink undies when they wash their unmentionables along with their shop towels.

Of course, your answer might be more plausible.

Comment: Dude, you never, ever wash a shop towel with clothes you want to wear again!

Comment: Wild guess, shop towel rental service started this years ago, they could tell at a quick glance if it was their rented towel or not when servicing a repair shop, don't want to clean someone else's greasy rags.

Comment: [This article](http://betterbusiness.torkusa.com/the-dirt-on-clean-laundry-the-truth-about-shop-rags/) seems to think it's to cover up old dirt and grime which doesn't wash away. BTW, you can get these in other colors, like blue. Red is just the most prevalent. You can buy them fairly cheap brand new, then wash then yourself. Most are 100% cotton. Anyway, no real clue why, just chiming in.

Comment: @Paulster2: Please change your comment to an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with motor vehicle maintenance or repair

Comment: @Chenmunka, which StackExchange community would you have put it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://betterbusiness.torkusa.com/the-dirt-on-clean-laundry-the-truth-about-shop-rags/) seems to think it's to cover up old dirt and grime which doesn't wash away. (NOTE: I don't agree with that for two reasons: 1) You can buy NEW rags fairly cheap. Most likely it costs as much or more to have old rags cleaned as it does to buy new. 2) The author of that article seems to be ragging on the rag industry ... I'm not buying what he says. Besides, I've never seen a cleaning company go back and dye the rags after cleaning.)

BTW, you can get these in other colors, like blue or white. Red is just the most prevalent. You can buy them fairly cheap brand new, then wash them yourself. Most are 100% cotton. Anyway, no real clue why, just chiming in.

Answer (score 0):

To make them easy to spot if left under the bonnet so as not to cause a fire.

Comment: @Solar_Mike hah, maybe. They tend to turn very dark tho, almost black even and blend in rather nicely all the same. A lot of it these days I suspect is probably just marketing standard based off some old ways of doing things.